# GWT HTML File Not Showing Correctly

Tags: html, gwt, configuration, compilation, production

My gwt compiled to production mode without any issues, but when I try to open the hosted.html file, all that I see is:

This html file is for Development Mode support.

Is this not the correct file or is there something wrong with my configuration or will it only work on a server?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `hosted.html` file is used only in development mode, and its job is to connect your app to the DevMode browser plugin. It gets loaded when you launch your app appending the `gwt.codesvr` query parameter to the URL.

After you have compiled your application, you generally [*] need a server to host it on. To put it simply, launch the DevMode without the `gwt.codesvr` query parameter, your compiled files (those giant `<hash>.cache.html`) will be picked up instead the `hosted.html`).

<sub>* I mean generally because if you do not use any server-side technology, but only client side code (ultimately compiled to js), you'd simply need to open up your html host page (that is not `hosted.html` but your `AppName.html` inside the `war` directory). Fairly uncommon though.</sub>

Comment: I'm just getting used to using gwt so as of now, I just have code that adds a label to the root panel, but when I open up my AppName.html file, it doesn't show anything. From what I understand from what you wrote, I should be able to see my label, correct? (Note that it does work correctly in development mode). Thanks.